# How can I determine the source of an ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I have a controller setup for an ajax call but I was just looking for a way of determining the source of the call.

So the Page that the call originated from.

*edit* I would like this check to be something done server side.

thanks!

Comment: Pass it as a parameter in the JS.

Comment: I don't want it to be something that can be seen that I am checking for. I would like to remain server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `Referer` header, which will be the page URL that the AJAX request was sent from.

However, not all browsers will send it.